# Find element by class that is not unique

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm having troubles with some elements that have the same class name but different attributes inside of them:

```
<td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="10" data-year="2017">
     <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">2</a></td>

<td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="11" data-year="2017">
     <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">2</a></td>
```

Want to choose the second element that has `data-month="11"` in it .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below xpath :

```
//td[@data-month='11']/a
```

Change version of CSSSelector is

```
td[data-month='11']>a
```